Using @amazon-sumerian-hosts/babylon in my angular project, facing issue to load the character in DOM getting error host.AnimationFeature is undefined
Using the npm i @amazon-sumerian-hosts/babylon in my angular project, facing issue to load the character in DOM getting error host.AnimationFeature is undefined
enter image description here expacting this
enter image description here this is i am getting
